# The equidistant set of a closed set 2

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $F$ be a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^m$ with $m\geq2$. For $r>0$, let $F_r$ be the set of points $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that dist($x,F)=r$ (distance between $x$ and $F$). Notice that if $F$ is not connected, then $F_r$ mais also be disconnected. Now suppose for some $0<r<\sqrt2$, the set $F_r$ has a bounded component; that is for some $R>0$ a component of $F_r$ is contained in the ball centered at the origin with  radius $R$. Can we say that for all $r<\rho<\sqrt2$ the set $F_\rho$ has also a bounded component? (in the first version of this question $\rho<r$, but now $\rho>r$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be the following subset of the $x$-axis in the plane: $\{(x,0): x\le-1$ or $0\le x\le1$ or $2\le x\}$.
Sketch the sets $F_r$, you'll see that it has a bounded component iff $r<\frac12$.